# Is codecvt not a std header?

Tags: c++, c++11, codecvt

This code compiles with Visual C++ 11 and runs as expected on Windows 7 but fails to compile using either MinGW 4.7.0 on Windows 7 or gcc 4.8.0 on Linux. Compiling with `-std=c++11` flag

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

// convert UTF-8 string to wstring
std::wstring utf8_to_wstring (const std::string& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.from_bytes(str);
}

// convert wstring to UTF-8 string
std::string wstring_to_utf8 (const std::wstring& str)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
    return myconv.to_bytes(str);
}
```

Error:

> codecvt: No such file or directory.

Comment: Note that the compilers that have implemented C++11 codecvt (e.g. MSVC), are most probably going to deprecate it by this C++17 paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html. Unless the "Other Directions" in the paper take precedence.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reason why GCC rejects this code is simple: libstdc++ doesn't support `<codecvt>` yet.

The [C++11 support status page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) confirms this:

> 22.5  Standard code conversion facets N

Comment: It would seem normal that it doesn't support `<codecvt>`, because there is no such file in the standard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: there is. What do you think that "22.5" refers to? It's the section where `<codecvt>` is defined.

Comment: Another C++11 feature, I see.  (It would have made more sense to simply define the names, and use the existing facilities.)

Comment: Hi. I am still looking for a workaround. Does anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: @Hugues and Swtsvn: I had the same problem and solved it using boost.locale: See my answer below.

Answer (score 23):

The question was asked almost 3 years ago and I was surprised that I am also having same issue using Ubuntu 14.04 with fresh updates.

Second surprise, the link provided by @Fanael shows now:

> 22.5 Standard code conversion facets **Y**

So I searched which version of GCC would fully implement C++11. Turns out that full support was added in GCC 5:

https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html

> Full support for C++11, including the following new features:
>
> ...
>
> locale facets for Unicode conversion;
>
> ...

I would have been happy to put a comment on the answer if I had enough reputation :)

Answer (score 22):

A workaround using [Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html):

```
#include <boost/locale/encoding_utf.hpp>
#include <string>

using boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf;

std::wstring utf8_to_wstring(const std::string& str)
{
    return utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size());
}

std::string wstring_to_utf8(const std::wstring& str)
{
    return utf_to_utf<char>(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size());
}
```

Comment: Do you know of any boost-free solution?

Comment: None except for the other answers in this thread, I' am afraid. I hope you have a recent standard library implementation available which does no longer require this workaround.

Comment: Only got Gcc4.8.5 for bazel.

Comment: @Nikos yes, but we only have 4.8.5 :-(

Answer (score 2):

It works on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 5.3.