# Is the C++11 <codecvt> header available in the latest GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

After reading [Is `<codecvt>` not a standard header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615136/is-codecvt-not-a-std-header) I am not sure what to do as my Windows version of the codebase uses `<codecvt>` to convert between wide strings and strings. I currently use GCC 4.7 for Linux version of my code. Is `<codecvt>` also missing in the latest GCC? What would be a workaround?

BTW, as it's stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804298/how-to-convert-wstring-into-string) the following code wouldn't work with GCC:

```
wstring ws = L"hello";
string ns(ws.begin(), ws.end());
```

Comment: Look [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011).

Comment: The wstring is typedef of basic_string<wchar_t>. From the link n.m. provides GCC is only missing codecvt<char16_t> and codecvt<char32_t>. So your code snippet should work. Can you provide more detailed code which doesn't work?

Comment: The code above is not what I am trying to run.I am talking about codecvt specific stuff.The code above is not reliable  as it is stated in the SO thread and it sounds logical

Answer (score 1):

How about using `mbsrtowcs` and `wcsrtombs`? Though they come from C are not very convenient to use with `std::string` and `std::wstring` (but you can always make your own convenient C++ functions based on them). Besides, the conversion is performed based on the currently installed C locale. So, your example code snippet can be changed to
something like:

```
std::mbstate_t state = {};
const wchar_t* p = L"hello";
std::string ns(std::wcsrtombs(NULL, &p, 0, &state) + 1);
std::wcsrtombs(&ns[0], &p, ns.size(), &state);
ns.pop_back();
```